# Echo and datamash in same line

Tags: bash

I am working in a Bash script and I am trying to put some data in a file:

I have the following code:

```
    if [[ -f ./myfile ]]; then
        echo "$i option:$i" datamash mean 1 sstdev 1 < ./${file} >> ./myfile
    else
        echo "$i option:$i" datamash mean 1 sstdev 1 < ./${file} > ./myfile
    fi
```

The code runs, but the file looks like this:

```
    1 option:1 datamash mean 1 sstdev 1
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
    1 option:1 1234    5678
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Where are the `1234` and `5678` supposed to come from? Is `datamash` a command or something? BTW, if `myfile` doesn't exist, `> ./myfile` and `>> ./myfile` are equivalent (and the `./` is irrelevant); why not just always use `>> myfile`?

Comment: When I just use >> it wouldn't create a new file if there wasn't any. Data comes from a file but I didn't show that code. Datamash is a command with which you can calculate stuff like the minimum and average. I already solved my problem myself, do I have to edit my question now?

Comment: You should clarify your question (something like "I want to run the `datamash` command with its input from `${file}`, and include its output in what's written to the file."), and then post your solution as an answer.

Comment: As for `>>`, according to the [bash man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), "Redirection of output in this fashion (i.e. [*n*]`>>`*word*) causes the file whose name results from the expansion of *word* to be opened for appending on file descriptor *n*, or the standard output (file descriptor 1) if *n* is not specified. **If the file does not exist it is created**."

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying is just passing datamash etc. as extra arguments to `echo`, when it's actually a command you want executed. I'd do something like

```
(echo "$i option:$i"; datamash mean 1 sstdev 1 < ./${file}) >> ./myfile
```

which redirects both `echo` and `datamash`'s output to `./myfile` all in one go. Note the semicolon separating the two different commands.

As noted in the comments, there's no need for the `if` stuff testing to see if `./myfile` already exists or not; `>>` will create it if needed.